# Seven true/false questions about vector spaces and linear mapping.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $v_1$ and $v_2$ be different vectors in an $n$-dimensional vectorspace $V$.

It is known for, $f: V  \rightarrow V$ that   $f(v_1) = f(v_2)$. Which of these statements are true?

**1. The range for $f$ is the entirety of $V$**

**2. If the equation, $f(x)=b$ for a $b \in V$ has a solution, then it always has more than one solution**

**3. If $dim(V)$ is an odd number, then the kernel and the range can have the same dimension**

**4. The kernel for $f$ consists of only the zero vector**

**5. $f(v_1-v_2)=0$**

**6. The mapping matrix is in square form ($n*n$)**

**7. Let $F$ denote a mapping matrix for $f$. The determinant of $F$ is not zero.**

It turns out the true statements are 2, 5, and 6.

Can anyone explain to me why these are the true statements?

My initial thought was that 4, 5, 7 are the true statements, but it turns out that this is completely wrong.

Comment: $(4)$ is false and it it easy to see from $(5)$. If $f(v_1-v_2)=0$ and $v_1-v_2\neq 0$, the kernel of $f$ cannot be only the zero vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $v_1 \ne v_2$, $v_1 - v_2 \ne 0$, so $v_1 - v_2$ is a non-zero vector in the null space of $f$. We will use this fact.

1) Because $f$ has non-zero nullity, by the rank-nullity theorem, $f$ does not have full rank.

2) Another solution is $f(x + v_1 - v_2) = f(x) + 0 = f(x)$. This is because $f$ is linear.

3) If the rank and nullity are $m$, then $\dim V = 2m$ by the rank nullity theorem, and $2m$ is even.

4) False by the fact above

5) True by the fact above

6) True because the dimensions of the matrix are the dimensions of the vector spaces

7) $f$ does not have full rank, and therefore the determinant is zero,.